# Robotium set activity variable value navigating from another

Tags: android, testing, robotium

I have  two activities, **ActivityA** and **ActivityB**. ActivityA displaying a list and ActivityB displaying details of list. I have some variable on ActivityB which i want to change run-time to test the outcome. I can not test the ActivityB directly as ActivityB populates/gathers data from ActivityA. Thus starting from ActivityA, I'm going to ActivityB. Now how can I set the variable value on ActivityB. Please help me.

Inside Robotium test class.

```
 solo.assertCurrentActivity(getActivity().getClass().getSimpleName(), "ActivityA");
 solo.clickInList(1);
 // Now I'm on ActivityB and ActivityB has a boolean isSuccess = false;
 // I want to set isSuccess = true; and test the remaining.
```

experts please help me on this.
Thanks!
@yup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to **mock** the data there. Before goint to AcyivityB, you would have to mock the data, which would be used in ActivityB. If the mock data would be available before call of ActivityB then ActivityB will use the available mock data. For that you can create a separate mock class, which would extend the class from main project which is responsible for providing data to ActivityB. There you can set the values to desired variable in mock class and can call the function before clicking button in ActiviryA, so that, the mock data would be available for ActivityB.

Comment: When I'm going to ActivityB from ActivityA, already data is populating to activityB. But what I want, inside activityB some methods are there, those generates some optput after certain operation. I want to set the output of those method. How to access them/set value to them?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. Make some tricky changes. Use `SharedPreferences` to handle the intermediate value inside the activity and form the from testClass changes the value of `SharedPreferences` data.